# Uso de Macbook para flujo de desarrollo

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, macos, sublimetext3, sftp

---

En mi actual trabajo soy el único desarrollador de software y especialmente de dedico al desarrollo web (al menos es lo que más hago). 
Anteriormente usaba una laptop con Ubuntu nativo, con dos máquinas virtuales para servidores de prueba (uno para base de datos y otro para la aplicación principal) y me era muy práctico (aunque no estoy seguro si era la mejor opción) usar la característica de Nautilus para conectar por sftp a la máquina virtual de la aplicación y usarlo como disco nativo de la computadora y desde ahí abrir el proyecto entero con Visual Studio Code o con Sublime Text para corregir errores e implementar nuevas características en un ambiente controlado previo a hacer un commit en Git y actualizar los servidores reales.

---

Mi problemática es la siguiente: recientemente se me dio la oportunidad de adquirir un Macbook Pro por recomendación de muchos programadores colegas de otros trabajos. Pero veo que no encuentro una opción parecida a la conexión que yo podía hacer con Nautilus para sftp, y el usar clientes como filezilla o similares al menos desconozco cómo abrir una carpeta completa del proyecto en un editor de texto como sublime text o VSC o cualquier otro y en mis intentos fallidos únicamente he podido abrir un solo archivo a la vez.

---

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo es el flujo de trabajo en una empresa con estas características? ¿Se usa sftp para manipular los archivos en servidores de prueba? o ¿de qué otra manera puedo cambiar el flujo de trabajo? Gracias y que tengan un excelente día.

Comment: GIT tal vez?...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los flujos de trabajo dependen totalmente de cada empresa, no hay una respuesta a eso. Yo paso mis archivos con WINscp. Lo cual no quiere decir ni que este bien ni mal.

Comment: Lamento si te molestó la pregunta, la verdad soy muy novato como desarrollador, eso que comentas de Git lo haría con las ramas? o de qué manera se puede hacer sin tener que ir haciendo un commit hacia una rama simplemente si hago un cambio de color o alguna cosa de ese estilo

Comment: Te agradezco mucho gbianchi, justo ando buscando alternativas, también vi esa que tú comentas y quiero explorar varias para ver cuál se ajusta mejor